# fetching multiple images from mysql database

Tags: php, html

I have been trying to insert multiple images in mysql database. After using below code, it was inserted in the database along with other fields as array. But now I am unable to fetch array to display images.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$title = $_POST['title'];

$description = $_POST['description'];

$price = $_POST['price'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
$nights = $_POST['nights'];
$people = $_POST['people'];
$hotel_rating = $_POST['hotel_rating'];
$images_name = $_FILES['images']['name'];
$images_type = $_FILES['images']['type'];
$images_size = $_FILES['images']['size'];
$images_tmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
$inclusion = $_POST['inclusion'];
$exclusion = $_POST['exclusion'];
$date = date('d/m/y');
$category = $_POST['category'];


if($title == '' or $category == '' or $description == '' or $price == '' or $days == '' or $nights =='' or $people =='' or $hotel_rating==''
or $images_name == '' or $inclusion =='' or $exclusion== ''){
    echo "<script>alert('Please fill all fields!')</script>";
    exit();
}
    for($i = 0; $i< count($images_tmp)-1; $i++){
        if($images_type[$i] == "image/jpeg" or $images_type[$i] == "image/png" or $images_type[$i] == "image/gif"){
    if($images_size[$i] <= 150000 && $images_size[$i] >= 100000){
        move_uploaded_file($images_tmp[$i], "images1/".$images_name[$i]);
        }
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('Please upload image between 100kb and 150kb only.')</script>";
        exit();
    }
    }
else{
echo "<script>alert('Image type is invalid!')</script>";
exit();
}`
```

I am using the following code to fetch images.

```
<img src = "<?php echo $images; ?>>
```

Can anyone help me that what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance. Following is the code missing for variable initialization:

```
    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){
$query = "select * from post order by 1 DESC LIMIT 0,4";
$run = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
    $post_id = $row['post_id'];
    $title = $row['post_title'];
    $description = substr($row['post_desc'], 0, 300);
    $price = $row['post_price'];
    $days = $row['post_days'];
    $nights = $row['post_nights'];
    $people = $row['post_people'];
    $hotel_rating = $row['post_hotel'];
    $images = array('images1/'.$row['post_images']);
    $inclusion = $row['post_include'];
    $exclusion = $row['post_ninclude'];
    $date = $row['post_date']; ?>       
    <!-- Item -->
    <div class="item clearfix rating_5">
    <div class="item_image"><img src = "<?php echo $images; ?>" width="500" height="400" style="width:100%; height:400px; object-fit: cover;" alt="Image cannot be displayed"></div>
```

Comment: For one, there's a quote missing in `<img src = "<?php echo $images; ?>>`. I can't see where that variable is set though.

Comment: There's also no database code where you're fetching from.

Comment: In given code is no communication with database. No inserts, no selects. Please add corresponding code.

Comment: I just edited my post giving the missing code.

Answer (score 0):

If the `$images` variable is array of images, you have to do at least

```
<?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
    <img src="<?= $image ?>">
<?php endforeach ?>
```

But in your code is no communication with database, no `$images` variable initialization, nothing. So only we can do is guess.

Comment: I tried doing this way but encountered an error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\Softwares\xampp\htdocs\Goutam\functions\functions.php on line 65". I have edited my post to clarify the variable initialization. I am doing anything wrong in that part?

Comment: Thank you for editing the code. You can do `var_dump($images)` to see variable contents. In your code you are doing `$images = array('images1/'.$row['post_images']);` - the array is useless here. You can simply do `$image = 'images1/'.$row['post_images'];` and then you can `echo $image`. If you have images in array (current code), you need to do that foreach thing posted in answer above. Because if you do `echo $images`, you are trying to echo whole array and it's not usable in this case.

Comment: $images = 'images1/'.$row['post_images']; .......... <div class="item_image"><?php foreach($images as $image): ?><img src = "<?= $image ?>""><?php endforeach?></div>....... even after this I got error **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in**

Comment: If you are using `foreach`, variable `$images` must be array! You have it as string now, so there is no reason to use foreach. Just make images array and use foreach or make images string and use just echo. But do not combine that.

Answer (score -2):

regardless for all of the mentioned code but in your img tag you have to close the src attribute.